# How to install Websphere Application Server using Puppet tool

Tags: linux, automation, websphere, puppet

My team wants to automate the Websphere installation on Linux servers using Puppet automation tool. We have a Linux server and Binaries of Websphere Application Server ND are available.How can i install Websphere Application Server ND using Puppet. I am very new to Puppet. 
Note: The Websphere installation just contains few commands(no GUI)

Thanks,
Kumar.

Answer (score 1):

Once you learn the basics of puppet, I suspect you'll know exactly what to do with the WebSphere Application Server ND integration available here:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-websphere

I don't think the Q&A format here is going to summarize how to use complex config management software to install complex enterprise software.

Comment: Thanks Covener. This link looks good and promising.